# Can't open office apps - "Install failed. Please contact your software vendor"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, windows-update, microsoft-store

I have Office 2016 on my pc, and I have used it for more than a year with no issue, however today I tried to open some files from excel or word, and when I try it gives me the following error: "Install failed. Please contact your software vendor".

I tried opening the program itself, and it doesn't do anything, doesn't even open the error message like before.

And I tried to go to the microsoft store, and maybe launch it from there, and when I tried, it started to update something, and after few minutes it just said it failed and gave me an a error number 0x8007000D.

What can I do to fix my Office, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Microsoft Store version of Office 2016 retail? If so, you can try to [fix problems with apps from Microsoft Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027498/microsoft-store-fix-problems-with-apps).

If you using desktop version of Office 2016, you can try to [repair your Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) from Control Panel.

If the issue persists, I'd recommend [uninstalling and reinstalling Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8).

Comment: First, I am using Office 2016 Desktop version, but I tried everything mentioned in the first link you gave me, nothing worked.
Then, I tried repairing which didn't work as well, but I reinstalled and it did work now, but I looked for a better solution than having to reinstall whenever this problem occures. But thanks for trying to help :)